# SiteCollection not available after the DB was moved into a different volume/drive by DB Admin

Tags: 2013, site-collection, sql

I ran the below command to create a NewSiteCollection and new DB for Legal Team

```
 Add-PSSnapIn Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
    New-SPContentDatabase "SP_Content_ABCLegal" -DatabaseServer "sql01" -WebApplication http://sp2013.abc.com
    New-SPSite -Url http://sp2013.abc.com/teams/legal -OwnerAlias lowes\johndoe -ContentDatabase SP_Content_ABCLegal -Template STS#0 -Name "ABC Legal"
```

Now DB Admin contacted me and informed me can I move this DB (SP_Content_ABCLegal) to a different volume with a lot of space and she said it would take 2 seconds and I said yes go ahead and ever since she did that site collection is not available.

After I dug deep into the issue and found out that the I should be using the SQLCluster name (sql01) instead of SQL Server name (sql01) is there a way to fix it or do I have to delete everything and redo this again. Please advise
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can detach the content database from central admin and then reattach using the correct `SQLCluster` Name. You dont need to delete anything.

[Attach or detach content databases in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628582.aspx)